# this.$set() is not working in vue2.0 with laravel

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, vuejs2

Am trying to set some data in vue js and access them in the view.

my vue method,

```
getVueItems: function(){
        var vm = this;
        axios.get('/someuri').then(function(response)  {
        vm.$set(this,'items', response.data);
      });
    },
```

in my view,

```
<tr v-for="item in items">
        <td>@{{ item.id }}</td>
        <td>@{{ item.name }}</td>
</tr>
```

The route is returning the result, but unable to set it to `items` and then loop them in the view.

Am I doing something wrong. Any workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take advantage of the es2015 syntax that binds this automatically...

```
getVueItems: function(){
        axios.get('/someuri').then(response => {
        this.items = response.data;
      });
    },
```